# Mocha.js test with Chai.js not working in asserting numeric values

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, assert, chai

I am facing a problem in writing a test case using Mocha and Chai. In the following code value of `n` is 1. I checked it using `console.log()`. Though I am testing this value against `0` the test is still passing. Actually it doesn't matter against what value `n` is tested, the test is passing anyway. What is the problem in it? Can anyone help?

```
it("Should have 1 variables", function(){                                    
    var variable_count = require("../../lib/variable_count").variable_count; 
    var file = __dirname + '/cases/case_3.json';                             
    jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {                                                            
        var n = variable_count(obj);                                                                        
        expect(n).to.equal(0);                                                                         
        assert.strictEqual(n, 0);                                                                           
    });                                                                                                     
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your code is asynchronous (because of `jsonfile.readFile()`), but your test is synchronous.

To make the test asynchronous, so it waits for a result, you can use the following:

```
it("Should have 1 variables", function(done) {
  var variable_count = require("../../lib/variable_count").variable_count;
  var file = __dirname + '/cases/case_3.json';
  jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
    var n = variable_count(obj);
    expect(n).to.equal(0);
    assert.strictEqual(n, 0);
    done();
  });
});
```

More info [here](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).